# Modeling scalar control of PMSM

Tags: motor, control, modeling, synchronous-motor

I have met with a scalar control algorithm for a permanent magnet synchronous motor. I haven´t heard about it before so I decided to develop a dynamic model to further analyze this control algorithm. Unfortunatelly I haven´t got the Matlab with the SimPowerSystems library so I decided to create this model in Scilab.

I have been using below given equations for PMSM simulation:

\$\frac{\mathrm{d}i_d}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{L_d}\cdot(u_d-R\cdot i_q+L_q\cdot\omega_e\cdot i_q), \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}i_q}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{L_q}\cdot(u_q-R\cdot i_q-L_d\cdot\omega_e\cdot i_d - \omega_e\cdot\psi_m), \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}\omega_m}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{J}\cdot(1.5\cdot p\cdot\psi_m\cdot i_q - T_l),\\
\omega_e = p\cdot\omega_m\$

where \$p\$ is number of pole pairs

The parameters of the model:

\$L_d = 1.365\cdot10^{-3}\,H \\
  L_q = 1.365\cdot10^{-3}\,H \\
    R = 0.416\,\Omega \\ 
    \psi_m = 0.166\,Wb \\
    p = 2 \\
    J = 3.4\cdot10^{-4}\,kg\cdot m^2 \\
    kF= \frac{3.2}{(2\cdot\pi\cdot\frac{1200}{60})^2}\,\frac{N\cdot m}{(rad\cdot s^{-1})^2}\$

Here is my overall simulation model
[image]

The motor is loaded by below given torque

\$T_l = kF\cdot\omega^2\$
which is removed in step wise manner at \$t=0.4\,s\$

The **U/f block**
[image]

The **PMSM Model block**
[image]

The **Inverse Park Transform block**
[image]

The **Inverse Clarke Transform block**
[image]

Ther results are following

Stator currents
[image]

Motor torque
[image]

Reference and actual mechanical speed
[image]

Stator voltage in q axis
[image]

I have doubts about correctness of my model due to the fact that the actual motor speed differs from the reference speed. I expected that they will equal because of the modeled machine is a synchronous motor. Does anybody know where I did a mistake? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried with the power invariant Clarke transform?

Comment: @a concerned citizen Thank you for your reaction. Do you mean changing the gains in the Inverse Clarke Transform block?

Comment: Yes, but now I realize the matrix is only for displaying the currents. Maybe there are similar scaling coefficients that need to be added when using the dq equations?

Comment: As far as I know the Park transformation only realizes rotation of coordinate system via multiplying by \$e^{j\phi}\$ and does not change module of the space vector.

Comment: Yes, but you don't only apply the Park transform to get to the dq-reference frame. That is, it's not a simple matter of multiplying with a sin/cos and adding/subtracting in a 3phase to a 2phase, the Clarke matrix, or, at least, the coefficients are also there. That \$e^{j\phi}\$ has meaning in an orthogonal system, not a 3phase, so you first apply 3->2 and then sin/cos, unless you complicate with doing it directly, but even then you have scaling coefficients. That's what I referred to when I mentioned the scaling coefficients. But I am also not sure, that's why I'm stuck with comments.

Comment: a concerned citizen, I am sorry but I don't understand your last comment. Please can you tell me in simpler way where do you think the problem could be? Thanks.

Comment: I meant the equations where you started from, since they're in the dq frame, I thought you arrived at them by first transforming from 3->2 phase, and that conversion has a missing scaling coefficient (\$\frac23\$ or \$\sqrt\frac23\$)? If not, then this is not the problem.

Comment: @Steve am I correct to assume your actual speed is (1/sqrt(2)) of the reference speed? If so, did you check your U/f block? Does the expression 40/sqrt(3)*sqrt(2) actually evaluate to what you expect?

Comment: @xuva thank you for your reaction. Yes you are correct. The actual speed is approximately \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$ of reference speed. My intention was to have \$\frac{40}{\sqrt{3}} V\$ for stator frequency \$40 Hz\$. Because of usage of the amplitude invariant form of the Clarke transform I multiplied the U/f block output by \$\sqrt{2}\$.

Comment: @Steve Does your reference specifically say Ud = 0? This seem very unlikely to me in a V/f control of a machine because the V/f is agnostic of the rotating system. Do you get the same results if you apply the Park transform to the command to get Ud & Uq? Probe all the variables, the sudden collapse of the current indicate that either a part of your model is unstable or that the machine cannot reach the command due to the construction of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

The Inverse Clarke Transform block: x_c is -(x_a + x_b)

Comment: Can you expand this answer?